# Treating dummy variables that describe characteristics of another (also in the dataset)

Tags: regression, logistic

In this question, we assume we have a health dataset with many triplets of dummy variables.

The dataset looks like this:

(existence_of_symptomA (1/0), symptomA_chronic (1/0), symptomA_persistent (1/0), existence_of_symptomB (1/0), symptomB_chronic (1/0), symptomB_persistent (1/0).......)

Each line represents a patient, and, the data are dummy because multiple symptoms may coexist per patient.

The outcome of interest is a dummy variable "hospital death" (1/0).

If you take a look at the data structure, you will notice that semantically the "existence_of_symptom" variables are the main ones, while the "symptom_chronic" and "symptom_persistent" describe characteristics of the "main" dummy variable.
If one wants to study the odds for death solely based on the existence of symptoms (just the existence_of_symptom variables) this would be a multiple binary logistic regression problem. This would create a model with the odds for death, for each symptom.

Here is the question: What would be the best approach to study the predictive contribution of the two extra "symptom_chronic" and "symptom_persistent" dummy variables per symptom?

Would you simply add everything together into the list of IVs to run the logistic regression?
Wouldn't this approach be incorrect?

To begin with, everyone without a symptom will always have values of 0 to the chronic and to the persistent variables as well! Also how will the model recognize and "account for" the fact that data should be seen as triplets?

Any insights?

Comment: Does it make sense to change "existence" "chronic" "persistent" to be "existent_not_chronic_not_persistent" "chronic" persistent"?

Answer (score 1):

If every disease is either chronic or persistent, then you can remove the disease variable.

If there are other ways to have a disease, then you can have diseasechronic, diseasepersistent and diseaseother for each.

This will avoid collinearity; it becomes a little more complex to look at the overall effet of disease.